# Data structure design

Tags: c#, data-structures

I got a big infrastructure with lots of nested classes and i'm looking for the right design pattern.

I will explain:
I got a class called "Title" and class called Item
A Title contain different items , each item contain different data

You can see in the schematic the Title contain also ItemList which contains more items.
each item can contain item.

I'm adding a schematic of the infrastructure , It looks like a non binary tree
[image]

I'm looking for the best data structure for this object,

Requirements:

1. With Node id and Tree Node i will be able to find the Node in a fast way
2. Good code maintainability
3. Can switch from flat to tree and from tree to flat

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what exactly do you want to do. How is the tree structure related to your nested classes? Are you trying to model your class structure or something like that? What exactly does “flat” mean?

Comment: And what do you mean by requirement #1? Do you mean finding a node just by its id? Or finding it by its id and its parent node?

Comment: I don't think that it's clear from the question whether the diagram shows a class structure or an object structure. Also I don't understand what exactly the term "nested classes" is supposed to mean here.

Comment: svick: just by node's id

Comment: The question is how to redesign the class in a good data structure way

Comment: Why not just store the nodes in the `NodeList` in a `Dictionary` where the key is the node ID? It's easy to understand, and you will have O(1) access within each `NodeList`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question seems to request a quick way to access nodes given their ID value regardless of the hierarchy. In this case you would probably be best off (as Daniel Gabriel suggests in the comments) to create a flat list optimized for "searching" the flat list of IDs, since your look-up operation doesn't care about the hierarchy. Just because you have your objects in a tree structure doesn't mean you can't also index them in another structure. A dictionary should be very good at this - the key could be an integer (or whatever your node id is) and the value could refer to the node object instance. You just have to remember to keep this structure in sync with your tree structure. Remove keys from the dictionary when nodes are removed, and add them to the dictionary when nodes are added (if the structure is dynamic).

This fulfills your requirement #1, and probably #2 (if you encapsulate the synchronization of the index in the same class if necessary). For #3 we may need more information, but if you keep these structures synchronized, you will always have access to both formats without a need for conversion. Should be very easy.

Here is some sample code that demonstrates how to encapsulate a structure that can provide both flat index and tree structures at all times:

```
class Program
{
  static void Main(string[] args)
  {
     Node<int, string> node1 = new Node<int, string>(1, "One");
     Node<int, string> node2 = new Node<int, string>(2, "Two");
     Node<int, string> node3 = new Node<int, string>(3, "Three");
     Node<int, string> node4 = new Node<int, string>(4, "Four");
     node2.Parent = node1;
     node3.Parent = node1;
     node4.Parent = node2;
     Console.WriteLine(node1.GetDump());

     Node<int, string> node5 = new Node<int, string>(5, "Five");
     // Test spliting the tree attaching it and it's subtree to another parent
     node2.Parent = node5;
     Console.WriteLine(node1.GetDump());
     Console.WriteLine(node5.GetDump());

     // Test re-attaching the detached parent as a child
     node1.Parent = node2;
     Console.WriteLine(node5.GetDump());

     // Test moving a node to another parent within the tree
     node1.Parent = node5;
     Console.WriteLine(node5.GetDump());
  }
}

/// <summary>
/// Create a tree structure whose nodes are of type T and are indexed by ID type I
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="I">Type of the index</typeparam>
/// <typeparam name="T">Type of the node</typeparam>
class Node<I, T>
{
  private Dictionary<I, Node<I, T>> rootIndex; // Shared flat index
  public I Id { get; private set; }
  public T Value { get; set; }
  private Node<I, T> parent;
  List<Node<I, T>> childNodes;

  public Node(I id, T value)
  {
     this.Id = id;
     this.Value = value;
     this.childNodes = new List<Node<I, T>>();
  }

  public string GetDump()
  {
     System.Text.StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
     if (parent == null)
     {
        foreach (KeyValuePair<I, Node<I,T>> node in rootIndex)
        {
           sb.Append(string.Format("{0}:{1} ", node.Key, node.Value.Value));
        }
        sb.AppendLine();
     }
     sb.AppendLine(string.Format("ID={0}, Value={1}, ParentId={2}", Id, Value,
        (parent == null)?"(null)":parent.Id.ToString()));
     foreach (Node<I, T> child in childNodes)
     {
        string childDump = child.GetDump();
        foreach (string line in childDump.Split(new string[] {Environment.NewLine},
           StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
        {
           sb.AppendLine("  " + line);
        }
     }
     return sb.ToString();
  }

  private void RemoveFromIndex(Dictionary<I, Node<I, T>> index)
  {
     index.Remove(Id);
     foreach(Node<I, T> node in childNodes)
        node.RemoveFromIndex(index);
  }

  private void ReplaceIndex(Dictionary<I, Node<I, T>> index)
  {
     rootIndex = index;
     rootIndex[Id] = this;
     foreach (Node<I, T> node in childNodes)
        node.ReplaceIndex(index);
  }

  public Node<I, T> Parent
  {
     get
     {
        return parent;
     }
     set
     {
        // If this node was in another tree, remove it from the other tree
        if (parent != null)
        {
           // If the tree is truly a separate tree, remove it and all nodes under
           // it from the old tree's index completely.
           if (value == null || (parent.rootIndex != value.rootIndex))
           {
              // Split the child's index from the parent's
              Dictionary<I, Node<I, T>> parentRootIndex = parent.rootIndex;
              RemoveFromIndex(parentRootIndex);
              rootIndex = new Dictionary<I, Node<I, T>>();
              ReplaceIndex(rootIndex);
           }

           // Remove it from it's old parent node's child collection
           parent.childNodes.Remove(this);
        }
        // These operations only apply to a node that is not being removed
        // from the tree
        if (value != null)
        {
           // If parent does not already have an index, create one with itself listed
           if (value.rootIndex == null)
           {
              value.rootIndex = new Dictionary<I, Node<I, T>>();
              value.rootIndex[value.Id] = value;
           }
           // If the index for the child node is separate form that of the parent
           // node, merge them as appropriate
           if (this.rootIndex != value.rootIndex)
           {
              // If this node has a complete index, merge the two tree indexes
              // into the parent's index
              if (this.rootIndex != null)
              {
                 foreach (KeyValuePair<I, Node<I, T>> node in rootIndex)
                 {
                    if (value.rootIndex.ContainsKey(node.Key))
                       throw new InvalidOperationException(string.Format(
                         "Node Id {0} in child tree already exists in the parent",
                         node.Key));
                    value.rootIndex[node.Key] = node.Value;
                 }
              }
              else
              {
                 // If this node does not have an index, it is not a tree;
                 // just add it to the parent's index.
                 if (value.rootIndex.ContainsKey(this.Id))
                    throw new InvalidOperationException(string.Format(
                    "Node Id {0} already exists in the parent's tree.", Id));
                 value.rootIndex[this.Id] = this;
              }
           }
           // Make all nodes in a tree refer to a common root index.
           this.rootIndex = value.rootIndex;
           // Attach this node to the tree via the parent's child collection.
           value.childNodes.Add(this);
        }
        // Attach this node to the tree via this node's parent property
        // (null if removing from the tree)
        this.parent = value;
     }
  }


}
```